# How to take Time Measurements using LT Spice

Tags: simulation, ltspice, measurement, capacitance, circuits

I've been fooling around with LT spice .MEAS feature for a while now and I just can't seem to determine how to take the time measurements I need for an assignment.

I can look at the time values on the waveform viewer and determine an estimated time, however given that LT spice is equipped with a measurement feature I'd like to be precise.

I have a simple circuit of a voltage source in series with a resistor and capacitor and I need to find the time that the voltage at the capacitor reaches 63% of the Voltage input. I think this is called Rise Time?

the command I've been trying is:

.MEAS Tran res1 FIND time WHEN V(Vout)=0.63(Vin) cross=5 TD=1m

essentially I need to find the time that it takes Vout to reach 3.15v (63% 5V(Vin))

Thanks

[image: My circuit and .meas command]

Answer (score 7):

You labeled the nodes `Vin` and `Vout`, and you are using the output node correctly (`V(Vout)`), but not the input node (`(Vin)` instead of `V(Vin)`).

You also forgot the asterisk for multiplication: `0.63*V(Vin)`. If you need to be more precise, use `(1-exp(-1))*V(Vin)`, impose a small timestep (1m of total time, or less), and, optional, add `.opt plotwinsize=0` to disable waveform compression. It doesn't look like you need it, though.

Finally, you use `cross=5` but you only have four rise/fall edges. Instead, use `rise=1` for the first rising edge, `rise=2` for the 2nd, etc. You don't need `td` here.

The new command should look like this:

```
.meas TRAN res1 FIND time WHEN V(Vout)=(1-exp(-1))*V(Vin) RISE=1
```

As a minor addition, you could use a bit sharper rise/fall edges on your source, to avoid wrong readings. `1u` would do just fine, without sacrificing decimals.

A little bit of attention can go a long way. This also implies no haste.