# measuring elapsed time when voltage reaches specific value in RC analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice

I am trying to measure the time a capacitor has reached  63.22% (1 tau) of the total voltage for a basic RC circuit. I can measure it directly from the `.TRAN` output, but when I try to use `.MEAS TRAN MyVal WHEN v(OUT) = (VMAX * 0.6322)`. In my application, VMAX = 5V, so (VMAX * 0.6322) = 3.161V. Attached below is a copy of my LTSpice schematic.
[image: DC circuit with a resistor and capacitor in parallel. Simulation commands are pulse(0 5 0 0.1u 0.1u 5m 10m) and .tran 0 10m 0 0.5m]

Comment: [Duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/490277/95619)? In truth, I don't really understand what you're asking.  Does the `.meas` not work? Does it work but wrong? Is there smoke?

Comment: Please show the **whole** schematic, including all text. Your schematic is now missing the .meas statement

Answer (score 0):

this statement measures the time constant, triggered on the falling edge.  that is a bit more interesting problem:
.meas TRAN TAU TRIG v(in)=2.5 TD=0 FALL=1 TARG V(out)=(1-0.6322)*5 TD=2m
When run in the schematic, it reports:
tau=0.000319437 FROM 0.00500015 TO 0.00531959