# How to find the time taken for the output to reach a certain value in LTSPICE?

Tags: ltspice

This question is software related. I just wanted to know if it was possible to get the time at which my circuit reaches a certain value without just running the cursor and getting a approximate value. For example if I have a RC circuit , plot the time at which the voltage across resistor reaches 1/2 * Vdd. Is there someway to do code it and get the exact answer? if yes can you please explain how it can be done?

Comment: Yes, it's called circuit analysis. For simple circuits- you can derive an equation representing the time domain response; then simply solve that equation for your conditions, e.g. time at Vout = Vdd/2.

Comment: For sure you can do it try to read here http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/_MEASURE_Evaluate_User_Defined_Electrical_Quantities.htm and here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtRaEHhMeCE

Comment: Aagh? I want to get it solved with LTSPICE not pen and paper. From my simulation results I want to find the time taken to reach a certain point @user_1818839

Comment: @HariKrishna What do you mean by "*plot the time at which the voltage across resistor reaches 1/2 * Vdd*"? A `.TRAN` simulation is done in a range of time, anything plotted will be a function of that whole timespan. Did you mean that you wanted your simulation to stop when it reaches that value? Otherwise, [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/490277/95619) might help.

Comment: You want to use the `.measure` statement to automate such measurements. You should be able to search for examples using that keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a .meas statement.

> .MEAS TRAN res4 FIND V(out) WHEN V(x)=3*V(y) rise=last
>
> Print the value of V(out) the last time the condition V(x)=3*V(y) is
> met when approached as V(x) increasing wrt 3*V(y). This will be
> labeled res4.
> Source: [LT wiki](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/_MEASURE_Evaluate_User_Defined_Electrical_Quantities.htm)

If I wanted to find the time when a node was at 0.5V, I would use a statement like this:

```
.meas TRAN newsignal2 FIND time WHEN 0.5=V(vout)
```

The results will show up in the spice error log, also if it says "Measurement [nameofsignal] FAIL'ed" that means the statement didn't find anything OR the syntax is wrong so this can make it difficult to debug.